# How to convert arguments of a function into a class in Python?

Tags: python, oop, python-class

I have function which has 10 argument but each time i call a function i dont need to pass all the 10 arguments as all the 10 arguments are not relevant each time the function is called.

```
def function(arg1:Optional[int] =0,arg2:Optional[int] =0,arg3:Optional[int] =0,
            arg4:Optional[int] =0,arg5:Optional[int] =0, arg6:Optional[str] =None, 
            arg7:Optional[str] =None,arg8:Optional[str]=None,arg9:Optional[str]=None,arg10:Optional[str] =None)

    pass
```

How to convert these arguments into a class and pass that class in the function as an argument each time the function needs to be called so that only relevant arguments get passed each time the function is called?

If any one can give some hints pls.

Comment: Since all the arguments are optional, just pass them by name. `function(arg2 = 10, arg7 = "foo")`

Comment: Creating a class isn't actually going to help with any of this.

Comment: If you need to pass them dynamically, use a dictionary, then use `function(**d)`

Comment: The function as of now looks clumsy so need to clean it a bit by seperating arguments into a class.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you might bundle all of those argument values into a `dataclass`:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Optional

@dataclass
class FunctionArgs:
    arg1: Optional[int] = 0
    arg2: Optional[int] = 0
    arg3: Optional[int] = 0
    arg4: Optional[int] = 0
    arg5: Optional[int] = 0
    arg6: Optional[str] = None
    arg7: Optional[str] = None
    arg8: Optional[str] = None
    arg9: Optional[str] = None
    arg10: Optional[str] = None
    

def function(args: FunctionArgs) -> None:
    pass
```

You'd then call the function like this:

```
function(FunctionArgs(arg4=10))
```

Comment: Even if we pass only arg4, the function returns other optional arguments as well. Is there a way to return only the arguments which are passed i.e. in the case above it should have only arg4

Comment: That question doesn't make sense.  What function are you talking about?